# C# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in Resources Menu?

Tags: c#

i need to add resources but i cant, the resources menu only shows up the Error in the title :/ i am using visual studio 2015 community edition ... without an engine

```
namespace DNGN
{
    partial class GameWindow
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.canvas = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // canvas
        // 
        this.canvas.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.canvas.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.canvas.Name = "canvas";
        this.canvas.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(Game.CANVAS_WIDTH, Game.CANVAS_HEIGHT);
        this.canvas.TabIndex = 0;
        this.canvas.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.canvas_Paint);
        // 
        // GameWindow
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(Game.CANVAS_WIDTH, Game.CANVAS_HEIGHT);
        this.Controls.Add(this.canvas);
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        this.MaximizeBox = false;
        this.Name = "GameWindow";
        this.Text = "DNGN Pre_Alpha";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.Panel canvas;
}
}
```

and here is this canvas width and height stuff :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;

namespace DNGN
{
    class Game
{

    public const int CANVAS_HEIGHT = 700;
    public const int CANVAS_WIDTH = 1200;
    private GraphicsEngine gEngine;

    public void startGraphics(Graphics g)
    {
        gEngine = new GraphicsEngine(g);
        gEngine.rendering = true;
        gEngine.init();
    }

    public void stopGame()
    {
        gEngine.stopRender();
    }

}
}
```

`

Comment: could you give me a link to that question ? ^^ please

Comment: ah okay saw it ... as far as i know i dont have a null object ...

Comment: and even if i remove the line in code which puts out that error, the error keeps to show up